# Why can I not scale right?

Tags: modeling

When I press "s" to scale it out like in many vids that I see, it just moves it to the side. I press "x" to make sure that im only moving on the x axis but it wont work. Please help me[image: ![here is what it does]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCb63.png)

[image: This is what it is when i start.]

Comment: Your pivot point is set to cursor, change it to median point

Answer (score 1):

Because that's exactly what pressing s with x does(look at your global orientation axes,x shows sideways).you might want to press y or -y to get what you want.